# React Intl with React 17

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I'm trying to upgrade a massive React project from 16 to 17 and it says that React Intl does not find the react version:

"npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.9 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-intl@2.9.0"

I know intl works with 17 if I do a force install, but I'm not quite sure of the consequences of doing so when I deploy to the server. Is there any workarounds for this?

Comment: So if you're upgrading React, why not update your other dependencies as well? `react-intl@2.9.0` is from 3! years ago.

Comment: @nbokmans Cause I read people still says it does not support react 17